# R: Extracting data from one df to another based on multiple variables matches?

Tags: r, match

I'm analyzing stock returns and have 1 data frame with tickers and position weights and another data frame with returns. I have included an example below. I need to extract return data from df 2 to the empty column in df 1 based on the ticker and date code. This is an example; there are many more tickers and dates. I have tried methods from previous posts unsuccessfully. I'm new to R. Can someone help? Thanks!

```
Df 1
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date code |  Ticker   | Return |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
|         1 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         1 | Ticker 4  |        |
|         1 | Ticker 5  |        |
|         2 | Ticker 1  |        |
|         2 | Ticker 10 |        |
|         2 | Ticker 8  |        |
|         3 | Ticker 9  |        |
|         3 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         3 | Ticker 7  |        |
|         4 | Ticker 5  |        |
|         4 | Ticker 5  |        |
|         4 | Ticker 10 |        |
|         5 | Ticker 8  |        |
|         5 | Ticker 1  |        |
|         5 | Ticker 7  |        |
|         6 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         6 | Ticker 9  |        |
|         6 | Ticker 1  |        |
|         7 | Ticker 6  |        |
|         7 | Ticker 8  |        |
|         7 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         8 | Ticker 4  |        |
|         8 | Ticker 5  |        |
|         8 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         9 | Ticker 5  |        |
|         9 | Ticker 3  |        |
|         9 | Ticker 9  |        |
|        10 | Ticker 5  |        |
|        10 | Ticker 5  |        |
|        10 | Ticker 3  |        |
+-----------+-----------+--------+


Df 2
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| Date code | Ticker 1 | Ticker 2 | Ticker 3 | Ticker 4 | Ticker 5 | Ticker 6 | Ticker 7 | Ticker 8 | Ticker 9 | Ticker 10 |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|         1 | 0%       | -3%      | 3%       | 1%       | -3%      | -1%      | 0%       | 0%       | -3%      | 0%        |
|         2 | -2%      | 1%       | -2%      | -3%      | -1%      | -2%      | -1%      | -2%      | -3%      | -1%       |
|         3 | 2%       | -2%      | 2%       | 1%       | -1%      | 2%       | 0%       | 3%       | -3%      | 1%        |
|         4 | 1%       | -2%      | 2%       | -1%      | 0%       | 0%       | -2%      | -3%      | 3%       | 3%        |
|         5 | 3%       | -2%      | 1%       | 0%       | 0%       | -1%      | 0%       | 3%       | 3%       | 0%        |
|         6 | -3%      | -3%      | 0%       | 2%       | 0%       | -3%      | 0%       | 0%       | -3%      | -2%       |
|         7 | -1%      | -2%      | -2%      | -1%      | 3%       | -3%      | -3%      | -2%      | 2%       | -3%       |
|         8 | 0%       | 1%       | 2%       | 2%       | -2%      | -3%      | -3%      | 3%       | 3%       | -3%       |
|         9 | -2%      | 2%       | 3%       | 2%       | 1%       | 3%       | 0%       | 2%       | 1%       | -3%       |
|        10 | 2%       | -2%      | -2%      | 0%       | -2%      | 1%       | 1%       | -3%      | 3%       | 1%        |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+


Excepted result:


+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date code |  Ticker   | Return |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
|         1 | Ticker 3  | 3%     |
|         1 | Ticker 4  | 1%     |
|         1 | Ticker 5  | -3%    |
|         2 | Ticker 1  | -2%    |
|         2 | Ticker 10 | -1%    |
|         2 | Ticker 8  | -2%    |
|         3 | Ticker 9  | -3%    |
|         3 | Ticker 3  | 2%     |
|         3 | Ticker 7  | 0%     |
|         4 | Ticker 5  | 0%     |
|         4 | Ticker 2  | -2%    |
|         4 | Ticker 10 | 3%     |
|         5 | Ticker 8  | 3%     |
|         5 | Ticker 1  | 3%     |
|         5 | Ticker 7  | 0%     |
|         6 | Ticker 3  | 0%     |
|         6 | Ticker 9  | -3%    |
|         6 | Ticker 1  | -3%    |
|         7 | Ticker 6  | -3%    |
|         7 | Ticker 8  | -2%    |
|         7 | Ticker 3  | -2%    |
|         8 | Ticker 4  | 1%     |
|         8 | Ticker 5  | -2%    |
|         8 | Ticker 3  | 2%     |
|         9 | Ticker 5  | 1%     |
|         9 | Ticker 3  | 3%     |
|         9 | Ticker 9  | 1%     |
|        10 | Ticker 5  | -2%    |
|        10 | Ticker 9  | 3%     |
|        10 | Ticker 3  | -2%    |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Suggest pivoting DF2 into a longer format and taking a look at the `match` function.

Comment: For a tidyverse version of Jay’s suggestion, use pivot_longer() on DF2, then a join, such as left_join(df1, df2long).